# Capture text displayed on JavaScript Alert message

Tags: javascript, html

Presently I don't know whether it is possible or not?

One of my scenario I want to capture text which will displayed in alert box on third party websites by injecting my JavaScript file.

Is there any way to capture / retrieve text content displayed on alert message box using JavaScript?

Comment: You cannot intercept third party websites, just as you cannot access them. SOP!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try shadowing the `alert` function:

```
window.alert = (function(al) {
    return function(text) {
        // your stuff here...
        al(text);
    };
})(window.alert);
```